# Can Record class be used to create RegInit?

Tags: scala, chisel

I am trying to use Record class to generate RegInit. This can help to dynamically create RegInit with other information in Module.

I am trying to use Record class to generate RegInit.
Here are my codes.

```
  class MyReg(reg_info: List[(String, UInt)]) extends Record {
    override def elements: ListMap[String, UInt] = ListMap(
      reg_info.map(
        x =>
          x._1 -> x._2
      ):_*
    )

    override def cloneType: MyReg.this.type = new MyReg(reg_info).asInstanceOf[this.type]
  }

class reg_test(reg_list: List[(String, String, List[(String, Int)])]) extends Module with RegSugar {
  val io = IO(new Bundle() {
    val a = Input(UInt(16.W))
    val b = Input(UInt(16.W))
    val d = Output(UInt(16.W))
    val e = Output(UInt(16.W))
  })

  val myBundle = new Bundle() {
    val a = UInt(16.W)
    val b = UInt(16.W)
  }
  val reg_init_bundle = RegInit(myBundle, 0.U.asTypeOf(myBundle))
  println(reg_init_bundle)
  reg_init_bundle.a := io.a
  reg_init_bundle.b := io.b

  val list_b = List(("a", UInt(16.W)), ("b", UInt(16.W)))
  val myRecord = new MyReg(list_b)

  val reg_init = RegInit(myRecord, 0.U.asTypeOf(myRecord))
  reg_init.elements("a") := io.a
  reg_init.elements("b") := io.b

  io.d := reg_init.elements("a") + reg_init.elements("b")
  io.e := reg_init_bundle.a + reg_init_bundle.b
}
```

In my sight, Bundle extends Record and if these code work on Bundle, they should also work on Record.
However, the error is reported on the line:

```
val reg_init = RegInit(myRecord, 0.U.asTypeOf(myRecord))
```

```
Exception in thread "main" chisel3.package$RebindingException: Attempted reassignment of binding to reg_test.reg_init_?.a: Wire[UInt<16>], from: ChildBinding(reg_test.reg_init_?: Reg[MyReg])
    at ... ()
    at implicit_test.reg_test.$anonfun$reg_init$2(reg_test.scala:61)
    at chisel3.internal.prefix$.apply(prefix.scala:48)
    at implicit_test.reg_test.$anonfun$reg_init$1(reg_test.scala:61)
    at chisel3.internal.plugin.package$.autoNameRecursively(package.scala:33)
    at implicit_test.reg_test.<init>(reg_test.scala:61)
    at implicit_test.reg_test$.$anonfun$verilogString$1(reg_test.scala:77)
    at ... ()
    at ... (Stack trace trimmed to user code only. Rerun with --full-stacktrace to see the full stack trace)
```

It seems that these codes can successfully generate RegInit with Bundle but failed to generate RegInit with Record.
Is that a way to generate RegInit with Record? or there is a compiler error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing your `MyReg` definition to

```
class MyReg(reg_info: List[(String, UInt)]) extends Record {
  override val elements: ListMap[String, UInt] = ListMap(
    reg_info.map(
      x =>
        x._1 -> x._2.cloneType
    ):_*
  )
}
```

I believe this might fix your problem. Cloning `x._2` makes sure you don't end up with multiple instances pointing to the same `Data` instance. Changing the `def elements` to `val elements` prevents chisel from complaining that multiple calls to `elements` returns the same thing.